# Nested std::bind in lambda cannot be casted to std::function (from void*)

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function, stdbind

I have to cast a member method call (**SystemUpdater::OnSystemUpdateCompletedHandler**) to void* in order to access as argument in a static C function.

**Snippet 1:**

```
updateDownloader->StartDownloadAsync(_updateRequest.url, "update-test", [&](std::string resultFile, Network::FileDownloaderResult_t result) {
                                this->updateHelper->StartUpdate(resultFile, std::bind(&SystemUpdater::OnSystemUpdateCompletedHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
updateDownloader->StartDownloadAsync(_updateRequest.url, "update-test", [&](std::string resultFile, Network::FileDownloaderResult_t result) {
                            this->updateHelper->StartUpdate(resultFile, [&](int result){OnSystemUpdateCompletedHandler(result); });
```

The second argument of StartUpdate is casted and executed in my static C function:

```
    (*((std::function<void(int)>*) userdata))(_result);
```

This cast and execution works with snippet 2 but NOT with snippet 1 (Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)).

Why?

StartUpdate is declared as:

```
UpdateResult_t StartUpdate(const std::string &path,const std::function<void(int)> &finishCallback)
```

Comment: You know, that a lambda is not a pointer to an `std::function` and that your second snippet is probably only working because the `operator ()` of `std::function` in the compiler you are using just happens to also work when `this` is pointing to certain lambda types? Or is your code of `StartUpdate` doing something to get that `userdata` to an `std::function` pointer?

Comment: Please be more specific than ”it doesn’t work”. And read about the [mcve].

Comment: @JeJo the `result` is whats passed through the `std::placeholders::_1` to the bound function.

Comment: Thanks for your replys!
@molbdnilo I know that my question is not that clear - thank you for the information. I will try to be more specific.

Comment: @yanick-salzmann I have added the declaration of StartUpdate. I dont do any magic with userdata in StartUpdate.

Comment: You need callback objects whose lifetime extends beyond the time when they’re called or using them is undefined.